# Redis multi level replication

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis

I have a situation where I need the following setup:
Redis A (Master) -> Redis B (Slave of A) -> Redis C (Slave of B).

The above config is due to the fact A is the master which synced to a different server yarn on a different cloud provider.

Redis B is a server that it's IP will not change and sits at the second cloud provider.

Redis C is an auto-scale server which needs to be synced with server B (sits in the same cloud provider).

The sync from A to B works well.
Syncing from B to C fails with a connection refused -

```
Could not connect to Redis at XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:6379: Connection refused
```

I've check the binding on the redis config and it OK.
The redis uses port 6379 on all nodes.

Comment: Can you actually connect using `redis-cli` (or even just `telnet`) from server C to server B?

Comment: I just found the reason.
I had an extra bind line that binded it to 127.0.0.1

Thanks.

Comment: Excellent - I love issues that get solved this easily ;)